# No route matches [PATCH] when using polymorphic_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error when submitting a form:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/foreclosure_defenses/4/properties"
```

Even though the html in the browser looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/foreclosure_defenses/4/properties" class="form-horizontal" id="edit_foreclosure_defense_4" method="post">
```

Since the new form renders a polymorphic model and a property model, I create my form as so:

```
<%= form_for @owner, url: polymorphic_path([@owner, @property]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :properties, @property do |property_builder| %>
    <%= render 'form', f: property_builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Why I am getting this PATCH error? The form is submitted with POST and should be going to CREATE method.

Here are the relevant routes:

```
foreclosure_defense_properties_path GET /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties(.:format)  properties#index

POST    /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties(.:format)  properties#create

new_foreclosure_defense_property_path   GET /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties/new(.:format)  properties#new

edit_foreclosure_defense_property_path  GET /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties/:id/edit(.:format) properties#edit

foreclosure_defense_property_path   GET /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties/:id(.:format)  properties#show

PATCH   /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties/:id(.:format)  properties#update

PUT /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties/:id(.:format)  properties#update

DELETE  /foreclosure_defenses/:foreclosure_defense_id/properties/:id(.:format)  properties#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that ended up working was explicitly defining the http method:

```
<%= form_for @owner, url: polymorphic_path([@owner, @property]), method: :post, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
```

Not sure why this was required. Poymorphic path should have been smart enough to determine it was a create action in my opinion.